# How can I use adb to send a longpress key event?

Tags: android, adb

I can use something like:

```
adb shell input keyevent 4
```

and this will send a single 'Back' button press to my device. How can I send a longpress?

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Since [this commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/11744d15364b16a976413599933ed1b1d59e4a6f) in Android 4.4 it is possibile to use:

```
adb shell input keyevent --longpress KEYCODE_L
```

[This other commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/9d83b4783c33f1fafc43f367503e129e5a5047fa) further improved the behaviour.

Comment: This should be the new answer since nearly everyone should be Android 4.4+

Comment: The major issue with this  is that some Android devices do not register this as long press, the delay is probably too short. Not that we would have much choice with how unreliable the sendevent is (Permission denied issues).

Answer (score 33):

You can try this command:

```
adb shell input touchscreen swipe 170 187 170 187 2000
```

Your application position on screen is
170, 187;  delay time is 2000 (ms);

Long press HOME key:

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 172 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0  0 0
timeout 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 172 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0  0 0
```

You can goto **cmd** and type **adb shell getevent | find "event2"** ; long press **HOME** key to see more.

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all. And when I use getevent I see `event0` when pressing keys, not `event2`.

Comment: what is the meaning of numbers like 0, 1, 172? Can you give me a link as a reference for knowing about these numbers and the way we should apply them

Comment: Found this useful for long pressing power key https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=37707876&postcount=2

Comment: command not found: timeout

Answer (score 1):

When you want to delete something or repeat some Event or just input a lot of numbers, you can use code like the following. It will imitate a **longpress** on a keyboard:

```
adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL KEYCODE_FORWARD_DEL //delete 3 times


adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_1 KEYCODE_1 KEYCODE_1 //input value '111'
```

You can repeat the event or input things without limits, just like a Longpress on the key. It's the same thing. You can define your own longpass and times Now

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me for reliably deleting a long string of text- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/tasker/LJhmfxT2mj8/y92jivjmZNIJ) discusses a similar problem, but the device in question (a Nexus One device)has the menu/home/back/search buttons as part of the touchscreen, not physical keys.

[This other one](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/ZpPBZMir5TE) appears to be more inline with injecting a physical key input, but requires accessing the *.kl file for your devices driver to determine the device, type, key-code, value-press, and value-release codes for that specific device.

However, the common link between the two appears to be

```
adb shell sleep n
```

, *where n is the length (in seconds) of the press duration.*

Hopefully this might be of some use.

Answer (score -1):

Well, [this developer link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#FLAG_LONG_PRESS) show the keycode is 128, which i already test, but no expected result

You can check [this](http://thecodeartist.blogspot.com/2011/03/simulating-keyevents-on-android-device.html) link and [this](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/development/pdk/docs/keymaps_keyboard_input.html) link. They show how to find it.

Comment: @whoabackoff anything happen if you send the OR of the flag and the keycode?

Comment: @chr the value of KEYCODE_BACK(4) OR FLAG_LONG_PRESS(128) is 132, which is just the value of KEYCODE_F2(132). This doesn't work.

Answer (score -2):

This might be too late to answer but surely will help others.

Please use below cmd to achieve long press.

adb shell input keyevent 5 sleep 5

Comment: Please share problem statement I'll provide solution.

Comment: **adb shell input keyevent 5 ; sleep 5**