# Can I use adb to simulate 3 long taps on a device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to simulate 3 (simultaneous not consecutive) long taps on an android device using adb.

The most promising lead I found was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142843/how-can-i-use-adb-to-send-a-longpress-key-event) but I haven't been able to  modify it so that I can use it.

Any thoughts on how to accomplish such feat?

Thanks.

Comment: Has this thread not been resolved? It would help a lot for other users and myself if you marked a solved problem. If you have found a better solution, please share with the community. Thank you.

Comment: I did manage to simulate a long tap with your response however, I did not manage to simulate 3 long taps at the same time.

Comment: k thanks. I happened to be using this solution again and I was wondering if there was an improvement.

Answer (score 13):

I found a very simple work around to simulate long touches. Simulate a swipe at the same point.

```
input swipe <x1> <y1> <x2> <y2> [duration in milliseconds]
```

Where x1 == x2, and y1 == y2.

This will simulate a swipe but since the your starting point and your end point are the same, it will act as if it was a lng press

Answer (score 7):

I've also been working on something related to this; and after loads of research, this is the best I've got - it can do exactly what you want, but there are a few drawbacks depending on your context.

It's simple, just send a low-level input events such as:

*simulating a touch down event*

```
sendevent /dev/input/event4 1 330 1         // touch down
sendevent /dev/input/event4 0 0 0           // end of report
```

Waiting after the touch down event is as if the user's finger is still on the device (*i.e.* a long press)

*simulating a touch release event*

```
sendevent /dev/input/event4 1 330 0         // touch release
sendevent /dev/input/event4 0 0 0           // end of report
```

**SYNTAX**

```
sendevent <device> <type> <code> <value>
```

For better documentation of the arguments, refer to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/kernel-headers/+/8bc979c0f7b0b30b579b38712a091e7d2037c77e/original/uapi/linux/input.h

**PROS:**

- I've found that using the *sendevent* command instead of the *input* command is significantly faster, most probably because you can send the specific low-level events you are interested in.
- You have a lot of control over a device, such as, the touchscreen, keyboard, buttons, thermometer, and etc...

**CONS:**

- You'll need to determine which device you are interested in manually. In my example I used */dev/input/event4*, but don't rely that this is the same on your device. The devices differ from phone-to-phone, so you probably need to use the command *getevent* and then manually determine which device is your touchscreen. This can become a real pain especially if you are trying to programmatically determine the touchscreen device for any android phone, simply because even the device name technically might differ from phone-to-phone.

**NOTE**

If you are looking for a simpler way to send an tap, you can use the command

```
input tap <x> <y>
```

but be warned, you don't have the luxury of determining how long to simulate the press down (*i.e.* no long press possible)

Good luck.

Comment: Thx for the infos! But, `getevent` requires root permissions, so this doesn't help on 99,9% of the devices.

Comment: @k1ll3r8e Note that I used `sendevent` and did this on an UNrooted device. I'm unsure about the modern OS's version but it worked on the devices I had at the time.