# How to send key down and key up events separately on android using ADB?

Tags: android, shell, adb

There's an [answered question about sending long presses on android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11142843/607407), the problem with it is that

- None of the answers actually work some use outdated API, some API that is too new
- I need to send key down event and only later decide to lift the key

From the top voted answer on linked question I have this code to start with:

```
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 172 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0  0 0
timeout 1
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 172 0
adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
```

These commands do not work, the author of the answer also didn't drop a single word about what the commands do and why. Through some experiments I figured out that:

- It must be `/dev/input/event0` instead of `event2`
- Changing any of the numbers results in nothing happening
- `adb shell sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0` is required. What does it do I don't know

Now **I need to send key up/down events for keys including those that are not on the device** (for example [KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN)), so `adb shell getevent` doesn't help that much - I can't press keys that are not there to be pressed. I'm working with Android 4.1.2 Samsung phone.

Also can anyone explain to me what is the `0 0 0` event?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can anyone explain this command fully adb shell sendevent \[device\] \[type\] \[code\] \[value\]?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17259809/can-anyone-explain-this-command-fully-adb-shell-sendevent-device-type-code)

Comment: @AlexP. I'm seriously getting fed up with people who vote as duplicate without thoroughly reading the question. Does the answer to question you linked to answer the question? No it doesn't! So what the hell? Is StackOverflow infected with some bots that cast close votes based on google search results?

Comment: Which key event are you trying to send? You mean "key" like the vol. up/down key or something else?

Comment: @TDG Good question, I added the info to the question. Basically any key defined in the [KeyEvent specs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) would be useful.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this long time ago, so I don't remember all the details. Hope I don't miss anything crucial...
All the input hardware that exist on the device are mapped into files (it's Linux, so of course everything is a file...). If you do `adb shell ls /dev/input` you see few `eventX` files, from `event0` and up. These files are mapped to the screen (the touch screen, not the display! which is usually `event2`), hard keys (usually `event0`), proximity sensor and all the other sensors/inputs of the device.
Another thing to bare in mind is these are not "normal" files, but "character files" - it's kind of a buffer that has data only at the moment that the relevant input device is activated. You can type `adb shell cat /dev/input/event0` and you won't see a thing until the moment you press some physical key on your device, like `home` or `vol up`. When you press a key, you see some gibrish on your screen, but that gibrish has meaning of course.
Type `adb pull /dev/input/event0`, press and release the `vol up` and press `ctrl-c` to stop the `pull` command. Now you'll have a binary file called `event0`, so open it with some Hex editor and you'll get something like -

> 59 07 00 00 80 C9 07 00 01 00 18 00 01 00 00 00
>    59 07 00 00 80 C9 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>    5A 07 00 00 96 60 01 00 01 00 18 00 00 00 00 00
>    5A 07 00 00 96 60 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

The first 8 bytes of each row are timestamp of the event and the other 8 bytes are the event itself.
**The first row** is pressing the `vol. up` key (little-endian):
`01 00` is the ID of the event. If you press two keys simultaneously you get two events with two IDs.
`18 00` is the **key code**.
`01 00` is the event type. `01` is press, `00` (like line 3) is release.
`00 00` (the last two bytes) are not in use here. For screen touch for example, it holds the screen coordinates.
**The second row** is some buffer cleaning/sync event that contains all zeros.
**The third row** is releasing the key. It's the same as the first row, but the event type is `00`.
**The fourth row** is again the sync event.
Now, if you create a file called `eventFile` that contains the first two rows, you actually have a sequence of pressing the `vol. up` key. You can inject it to the device with - `adb push eventFile /dev/input/event0` and you'll see that the `vol. up` key is pressed but not released - a long press. To release it, just send in another file with the other two lines. You don't have to worry about the time stamp, you can leave it as-is.
For different keys, you'll have to change the `key code` of course.
I've tried it on my device - Samsung S3 mini /4.1.2 with both `vol up/down` keys and it works. I didn't try it with non-existing keypad keys.

Comment: There is no such thing as "usual" input device file assignment - there are no rules. The exact binary format of the event depends on the kernel bitness - yours is for 32bit kernels. Also every input device has a feature bitmask defining supported events - you won't be able to inject an event with unsupported key code.

Comment: @AlexP. - "There is no such thing as "usual" input device file assignment" - Do you mean that event0 is not the hard keys on all devices? From what I recall, the touch screen and hard keys are always the same, but I don't know about the other sensors.

Comment: how many devices have you seen? I personally took part in developing over 50 android devices and I have seen about 200 other models and I am telling you - there are no rules.

Comment: Well, I've seen about a dozen different devices, but most (if not all) of them were Samsungs.

Answer (score 1):

To help anyone who might need this information later here's what I've pulled together from @TDG post and other StackOverflow answers.

There are different files available that map to device hardware, such as the touch screens or physical buttons. It's not clear if the same files map to the same hardware on all Android phones, but I would expect there are some devices out there that differ so be careful.

These files are called **/dev/input/eventX**, where X refers to a 0-indexed number for the hardware.

To find the correct file for the device you are interested in you can use `getevent`.

`adb shell su 0 getevent`

This will output the name and ID of each device. When you have the correct path you can start listening for incoming events:

`adb shell su 0 getevent /dev/input/event0`

When that's running trigger the event on your device, for instance press the button you're interested in. This will output something like:

```
0001 0095 00000001
0000 0000 00000000
0001 0095 00000000
0000 0000 00000000
```

These were the entries when I pressed and released a hardware button. Note that there are 2 sets for each event (first 2 are key down, second 2 are key up)

Note the values are in hex. Convert them to decimal. Use a calculator or hex2dec site to do this. You can then inject the events using `sendevent`

**Key down**

```
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 149 1 # Hex: 0001 0095 00000001
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0   # Hex: 0000 0000 00000000
```

**Key up**

```
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event0 1 149 0 # Hex: 0001 0095 00000000
adb shell su 0 sendevent /dev/input/event0 0 0 0   # Hex: 0000 0000 00000000
```